# Python Selenium, Dropdown Option Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting this error

**selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated**

For this line with `//option[. = 'Individual']`

```
dropdown = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#selectClaimantTypeContainer select")
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//option[. = 'Individual']"))).click()
```

I've added `WebDriverWait` and still the error persists?  The dropdown options are loaded dynamically via ajax.

How do i solve?  This is how the code looks with `WebDriverWait`

```
dropdown = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#selectClaimantTypeContainer select")
dropdown.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[. = 'Individual']").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a `Select` element there. So you need to select the desired `option` by value or by visible text, as following:

```py
dropdown = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#selectClaimantTypeContainer select")
dropdown.select_by_visible_text('Individual')
```